# floating frame gets overlapped by other elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a floating frame on page. I did not know how to create one, so I Googled and found [this website to create floating frame.](http://tools.seochat.com/tools/floating-layer//?tool=59) I am able to embed the frame into my page, but as the page has lots of other elements, it is overlapped by some or other elements in the `body`. I tried placing the div of frame at various parts of `body` but each time, some of elements overlap it.

I am placing the code which the website generates as a sample, (as code of my page is too long and generated by PHP, so avoiding it here)

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
<!--
isIE = document.all;
isNN =! document.all&&document.getElementById;
isN4 = document.layers;
isActive = false;

function MoveInit(e){

  topOne = isIE ? "BODY" : "HTML";

  whichOne = isIE 
      ? document.all.FloatingLayer 
      : document.getElementById("FloatingLayer");  

  ActiveOne = isIE 
      ? event.srcElement 
      : e.target;  

  while (ActiveOne.id!="titleBar"&&ActiveOne.tagName!=topOne){
    ActiveOne = isIE ? ActiveOne.parentElement : ActiveOne.parentNode;
  }  

  if (ActiveOne.id=="titleBar"){
    offsetx = isIE ? event.clientX : e.clientX;
    offsety = isIE ? event.clientY : e.clientY;
    nowX = parseInt(whichOne.style.left);
    nowY = parseInt(whichOne.style.top);
    MoveEnabled = true;
    document.onmousemove = Move;
  }
}

function Move(e){

  if (!MoveEnabled) return;

  whichOne.style.left=isIE 
      ? nowX+event.clientX-offsetx 
      : nowX+e.clientX-offsetx; 

  whichOne.style.top=isIE 
      ? nowY+event.clientY-offsety 
      : nowY+e.clientY-offsety;

  return false;  
}

function MoveN4(whatOne){

    if (!isN4) return;

    N4 = eval(whatOne);
    N4.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN|Event.MOUSEUP);
    N4.onmousedown = function(e){
        N4.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
        N4x=e.x;
        N4y=e.y;
    }

    N4.onmousemove = function(e){

    if (isActive){
      N4.moveBy(e.x-N4x,e.y-N4y);
      return false;
    }
  }

  N4.onmouseup = function(){
    N4.releaseEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
  }
}

function ToggleFloatingLayer(DivID, iState) // 1 visible, 0 hidden
{
    if(document.layers)    //NN4+
    {
       document.layers[DivID].visibility = iState ? "show" : "hide";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById)      //gecko(NN6) + IE 5+
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById(DivID);
        obj.style.visibility = iState ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }
    else if(document.all)   // IE 4
    {
        document.all[DivID].style.visibility = iState ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }
}

document.onmousedown = MoveInit;
document.onmouseup = Function("MoveEnabled=false");
// -->
</script>



<!-- Start Floating Layer -->
<div id="FloatingLayer"     style="position:absolute;width:250px;left:100px;top:100px;visibility:visible; border:solid     1px #FF6600;">
    <div id="titleBar" style="cursor:move; width:100%; position:relative; border-    bottom:solid 1px #FF6600; background-color:#FF9933;">
        <div id="title" style="margin-right:30px; padding-left:3px;">
            <font face="Arial" color="#333333">Layer Title</font>
        </div>
        <div id="closeX" style="cursor:hand; position:absolute; right:5px; top:0px;">
            <a href="#" onClick="ToggleFloatingLayer('FloatingLayer',0);return false"      style="text-decoration:none"><font color="#333333" size="2" face="arial">X</font></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="floatingContent" style="padding:3px; background-color:#CCCCCC;     color:#333333;">
        <!-- place your HTML content here-->
        Put text, tables or any other HTML contents here, as you would put
        in any other HTML page.
        ..... and more.

        <!-- End of content area -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Floating layer -->

<!-- To Show The Layer -->
<a href="javascript:ToggleFloatingLayer('FloatingLayer',1);">Show</a>
<input type="button" onClick="ToggleFloatingLayer('FloatingLayer',1);" value="Show     Layer">

<!-- To Hide The Layer -->
<a href="javascript:ToggleFloatingLayer('FloatingLayer',0);">Hide</a>
<input type="button" onClick="ToggleFloatingLayer('FloatingLayer',0);" value="Hide     Layer">
```

EDIT : I want to show SWF file embedded in a floating frame. If anyone has any alternatives for creating floating frames, like those Facebook shows nowadays for viewing photos, pointing me towards the right direction would be very helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is to do with [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Try adding this css style to your floating frame:

```
z-index: 99999;
```

Comment: adding this still overlaps things. I checked from browser element Inspector that the z-index was actually applied to `FloatingLayer` element.

Answer (score 0):

Either it is a problem with z-index, or embedded objects like Flash.

You could try to use a higher value of z-index for your floating frame, so that it appears on top of other elements. Also take a look at other elements' z-index... they may also have high z-indexes.

If your problem is with Flash objects, try this in your embed/object tag:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

As noted by this blog post: [Flash and the z-index problem, solved](http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/#comment-479)